# Why searching classes in classloader sometimes dont work?

Tags: java, classloader

My team is developing some resources that will be deployed as jar in some web projects. Inside the jar there is a class that find some client classes to load using reflection and put into a map, but we are facing a strange issue during the tests as in some clients the method that retrieve these classes just return an empty list!

So, we have 3 clients (counting the station using in the developing), 2 of the works fine but in one of them don't. And curiously in the developing station it works fine in the client but when trying to test it with JUNit, I mean, the classes are being scanned from inside the component itself we have the same problem, an empty list.

Here is the code that sometimes works, how can it be improved to works always?

```
public final static List<Class<?>> find(final String scannedPackage) {
    final ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    final String scannedPath = scannedPackage.replace(DOT, SLASH);
    final Enumeration<URL> resources;
    try {
        resources = classLoader.getResources(scannedPath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(BAD_PACKAGE_ERROR, scannedPath, scannedPackage), e);
    }
    final List<Class<?>> classes = new LinkedList<Class<?>>();
    while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
        final File file = new File(resources.nextElement().getFile());
        classes.addAll(find(file, scannedPackage));
    }
    return classes;
}
```

Comment: if there isn't anything different in the 3rd client, then there's no reason for it to systematically not to work

Comment: I'm surprised this works at all.  I have never seen any documentation indicating that a directory entry in a .jar or .zip file is guaranteed to be a loadable resource.  So it probably is dependent on the ClassLoader implementation:  some ClassLoaders support it, some don't.